# Bug report bug report?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

The full user guide [here](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/proxy/tutorial/full-user-guide/001-The_IBM_Q_Experience/001-Introducing_the_IBM_Q_Experience.html) states "If you find any bugs, please report them with our bug tracker, accessible via the little bug icon in the lower right-hand corner of each page."

[image: Wheres the bug icon?]

However, I was unable to find this bug icon. The arrow seen in the screenshot only returns you to the top of the page.

Then I found a link under "Documentation and Support" for bug reports. However, the link brought me to a page that told me "This invite link is no longer active."

[image: Documentation and Support]

[image: Slack invite link expired]

To conclude, I am trying to report a typo on the 'Introduction to Quantum Circuits'.

[image: Typo Correction]

See [Example 1](https://study.com/academy/lesson/how-to-find-a-column-vector.html)

[Inner Product Error](http://sharetechnote.com/html/Handbook_EngMath_Matrix_InnerProduct.html) - This is the same as a dot product right?

Comment: Bug report icon?